# OSX: git slow clone. How do I check if port 9418 is open?

Tags: macos, git

I have very slow git clone. How do I check if port 9418 is open?

Comment: If it were closed your clone wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, if your git clone works however slowly. (assuming you clone from `git:` repository).

Answer (score 1):

I use the following command line to check if port 9418 is open:

```
lsof -i :9418
```

to find the git service:

```
grep 9418  /etc/services
```